# MySQL Matching whitespace in Regex

Tags: mysql, regex, whitespace

I'm having a problem with the regex syntax in Mysql when it comes to matching whitespaces in Strings.

I have a database of Zipcodes in the format:
`1111 AA CITYNAME` or `1111 CITYNAME`.

From this, I want to extract the zipcode and the cityname, I used the following code:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS GET_POSTALCODE;
CREATE FUNCTION GET_POSTALCODE(input VARCHAR(255))
  RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
  BEGIN
    DECLARE output VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
    IF input LIKE '^[1-9][0-9]{3}[[:blank:]][A-Z]{2}[[:blank:]]%'
    THEN
      SET output = SUBSTRING(input, 1, 7);
    ELSE
      SET output = SUBSTRING(input, 1, 4);
    END IF;
    RETURN output;
  END
```

I would expect the result for a input string of `9741 NE Groningen` to be split up into `9741 NE` and `Groningen`.

But instead I get `9741` and `NE Groningen`.

I have tried all sorts of things to match the whitespace, which I think is the problem. I tried:

- `[[:blank:]]`
- `[:blank:]`
- `[[:space:]]`
- `[:space:]`
- and the `\s` method

`[:space:]` Should match all whitespaces, but yet again, same result.

Nothing I try seems to work, could you maybe point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: is this "AA" of "1111 AA CITYNAME" always two characters long or can it be more or less?

Comment: The letters are always 2, not more, but in some cases the 2 letters aren't supplied, and the 4 numbers are immediately followed by a space and the cityName

Comment: okay - i dont know further right now but perhaps this will point you in a better direction: \s+(?=\S*+$) will give you the last whitespace, but i dont get how to become the part after and before that.

Comment: Your task is best done _before_ inserting the data into a database.

Comment: Is this code actually used? According to MySQL specs 'like' does not work on regular expressions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Foreward

You can enable PCRE if you use [this library](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg#readme)

## Description

```regex
^([0-9]{4}(?:[[:blank:]]+[a-z]{2}(?=[[:blank:]]))?)[[:blank:]](.*$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- find the 4 digit codes followed by an optional two characters
- match the rest of the string which should be a city name

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/sE3xN7/4

**Sample text**

Note your examples only had 4 digit codes, so I took the liberty of adding an additional digit

```
1111 AA CITYNAME1
2222 CITYNAME2
3333 Las Vegas
4444 BB Las Vegas
9741 NE Groningen
```

**Sample Matches**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-7]   `1111 AA`
2.  [8-17]  `CITYNAME1`

MATCH 2
1.  [18-22] `2222`
2.  [23-32] `CITYNAME2`

MATCH 3
1.  [33-37] `3333`
2.  [38-47] `Las Vegas`

MATCH 4
1.  [48-55] `4444 BB`
2.  [56-65] `Las Vegas`

MATCH 5
1.  [66-73] `9741 NE`
2.  [74-83] `Groningen`
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{4}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (4 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [[:blank:]]+             whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                               (1 or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [a-z]{2}                 any character of: 'a' to 'z' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [[:blank:]]               whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [[:blank:]]                 whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                             "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```